# Using custom order to arrange rows after previous sorting with arrange

Tags: r, dplyr

I know this has already been asked, but I think my issue is a bit different (nevermind if it is in Portuguese).
I have this dataset:

```
 df <- cbind(c(rep(2012,6),rep(2016,6)),
         rep(c('Emp.total',
               'Fisicas.total',
               'Outros,total',
               'Politicos.total',
               'Receitas.total',
               'Proprio.total'),2),
         runif(12,0,1))

colnames(df) <- c('Year,'Variable','Value)
```

I want to order the rows to group first everything that has the same year. Afterwards, I want the `Variable` column to be ordered like this:

1. Receitas.total
2. Fisicas.total
3. Emp.total
4. Politicos.total
5. Proprio.total
6. Outros.total

I know I could use`arrange()` from `dplyr` to sort by the year. However, I do not know how to combine this with any routine using `factor` and `order` without messing up the previous ordering by year.

Any help? Thank you

Comment: For this you may need a customer order, i.e. `df[order(df[,1], factor(df[,2], levels = c('Receitas.total', ...'Outros.total'))),]`

Answer (score 6):

We create a custom `order` by converting the 'Variable' into `factor` with `levels` specified in the custom `order`

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
   arrange(Year, factor(Variable, levels = c('Receitas.total', 
       'Fisicas.total', 'Emp.total',  'Politicos.total', 
        'Proprio.total',  'Outros.total')))
# A tibble: 12 x 3
#    Year        Variable     Value
#   <dbl>           <chr>     <dbl>
# 1  2012  Receitas.total 0.6626196
# 2  2012   Fisicas.total 0.2248911
# 3  2012       Emp.total 0.2925740
# 4  2012 Politicos.total 0.5188971
# 5  2012   Proprio.total 0.9204438
# 6  2012    Outros,total 0.7042230
# 7  2016  Receitas.total 0.6048889
# 8  2016   Fisicas.total 0.7638205
# 9  2016       Emp.total 0.2797356
#10  2016 Politicos.total 0.2547251
#11  2016   Proprio.total 0.3707349
#12  2016    Outros,total 0.8016306
```

#### data

```
set.seed(24)
df <- data_frame(Year  =c(rep(2012,6),rep(2016,6)),
     Variable = rep(c('Emp.total',
           'Fisicas.total',
           'Outros,total',
           'Politicos.total',
           'Receitas.total',
           'Proprio.total'),2),
     Value = runif(12,0,1))
```